# Comparison-based algorithm that pairs the largest element with the smallest one in linear time

Tags: algorithm

Given an array of integers. I want to design a comparison-based algorithm
that pairs the largest element with the smallest one, the second largest one with the second smallest one and so on. Obviously, this is easy if I sort the array, but I want to do it in O(n) time. How can I possibly solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Well i can prove that it does not exists.

Let`s proof by contradiction: suppose there was such algorithm

- When we could get an array of kth min and kth max pairs.
- We could when get sorted array by taking all mins in order then all max in order,
- so we could get original array sorted in O(n) steps.
- So we could get a **comparision based** sorting algorithm that sorts in O(n)
- Yet it can be proven that comparision based sorting algorithm must take atleast n
  log n steps. (many proofs online. i.e. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lower-bound-on-comparison-based-sorting-algorithms/)
- Hence we have a contradiction so such algortihm does not
  exist.

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering if this could be done using dynamic programming.

Comment: @ExternalMan: this answer proves that there is no hope of beating O(N Log N). No hope. Even with hyperdynamic superprogramming.